# How to get own phone number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a device phone number programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644145/how-to-get-a-device-phone-number-programmatically)

Hi guys. I read that it is possible to get the phone number registered on iTunes. I want to work with this number, how can I get this? Is it really possible with iPhone SDK?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not permitted. If you want their number ask them for it.

If they trust you they can give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The method, that you can see in 1. answer is removed in iOS 4 and newer.

Please, know somebody an another method to get the phone number?