# Retrieving user sim number in Phonegap 3 / Cordova 3

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am working on an SMS app with `Cordova`/`Phonegap` and I want to retrieve the user's **SIM number** on Android and iOS device for authentication and verification purpose.

Can someone please point me to a plugin or a blog on how to go about that, since i have spent almost a week searching and even trying to manipulate the device API, but still to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see [this post](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/getting-imei-number-and-other-details.html) you may get some extra info on how to get info out of Android object TelephonyManager

Comment: I found two plugins ready-to-use: https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim and
http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/rotorgames/phonegap-telephonenumber-plugin Or you can still create your own as in _Mark Smit_'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to do this in IOS:

Refer : [Get the device's phone number programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644145/get-the-devices-phone-number-programmatically)

for android it should be easy to write such plugin yourself. you can get the number trough the telephony manager:

```
TelephonyManager tmanager;
tmanager= (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String number = tmanager.getLine1Number();
return fillPhoneNumber(number);
```

Howto make a plugin you can find here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html