# Obtaining a phone's telephone number

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am writing an IOS application in Swift (XCode 6) for iPhones and I need to get the telephone number assigned to the telephone running the app.

Searches have not found an answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: I hope you can't do it, is my thought.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to. Apple tends to make it difficult to obtain a device's phone number due to security concerns. Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios) question or possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644145/get-the-devices-phone-number-programmatically?lq=1) extension of that question for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to get the telephone number of the iPhone programmatically.