# How to get own mobile number from the iOS Device programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security, core-telephony

I want to get my own contact number for my app.

I have read some answers on the stack overflow but those were old.

So please let me know according to new guidelines of Apple, can we get mobile number?

Comment: is not possible in iOS . android we can get

Comment: Probably not, if you want it, ask the user to input, it's highly violated the privacy of user and Apple doesnt like it

Comment: Many communications apps ask for the phone number, including WhatsApp.  Many also use it for verification purposes, including FB and Google.  I've worked for companies with products which ask for the phone number.  Apple has never indicated this as a problem.

Comment: not possible in iOS, becoz is violating the Apple policy and will be rejected by Apple for security purpose.

Comment: @Avi 
So please let me know how to get the own contact number? if you have got any reference.

Comment: @Martin R

I asked this question again because that question is too old for now.
Apple always updates their terms and conditions that is why I am asking this.

Comment: It is the same question and the answer is still valid. In fact you have *accepted* an answer which just *links to that Q&A* as a reference.

Comment: @MartinR, Yes I accepted that answer according to the old references but I am still looking for the updated answer.

Comment: The answer is the same.  No update necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phone number is not accessible from any Apple public API which means you can't get it.

Comment: I read this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504478/ios-7-how-to-get-own-number-via-private-api

but as suggested that app must be rejected that is why I am asking for.

Comment: It's now possible in Xcode - check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004224/536214

Comment: @aqavi_paracha: It's not possible, the link you shared above shows how to set the content type for UITextField. It doesn't mean that you can fetch the phone number from the device. Apple won't let you to do so :)

Comment: @VishnuKumar.S . Yeah but when you set contentType to Mobile field, iOS gives you option to select Mobile number in mobile field, like we used to do in Web. So basically you get mobile number of the phone you're using the app in.

Answer (score 3):

The mobile number cannot be accessed without using any private API using which would lead to app rejection. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644145/get-the-devices-phone-number-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to get phone number of the device

Refer this link

[Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

[Get the device's phone number programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644145/get-the-devices-phone-number-programmatically)

Comment: In this case, 'This' should be 'It'.