# How to get Mobile phone Number using flutter Framework?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

How can I programmatically get the phone number of the device that is running my android app using Flutter?

I know we can do this easily in android studio using this syntax :

```dart
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

But how to do this using flutter ?

Comment: Check platform channels : https://flutter.io/platform-channels/
to call platform specific codes from flutter.

Comment: ah , good idea. i'll try it. thanks. 
even Still Waiting for flutter release date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no cross-platform solution for that as Apple restricts its iOS Apps and prohibit the access of the phone number. The only thing you can do is write a package which only supports Android and returns the phone number. Refer to:

[Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

[Get the device's phone number programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644145/get-the-devices-phone-number-programmatically)

**For Android:**

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone#2480307)

[Create a flutter package](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

**Edit 2019/09/03:**

Some apps like Snapchat bypass Apple's restriction by sending a sms from the users phone to a server which then returns the phone number. Here is a blog post about doing this with AWS:

[Capturing Mobile Phone Numbers](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2018/07/13/capturing-mobile-phone-numbers)

Comment: So for now, impossible to get phone number in ios, and phone number is not always available to obtain, right?

Comment: Yes and I don't think that Apple will ever allow this.